# в listView имеются checkBox'ы у некоторых из которых есть значение checked, как обнулить все значения checked разом?

Tags: c#, wpf

Заменить checked всех checkBox'ов в ListView на unchacked.

Пока дошел только до этого:

```
//var product = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as Product;
foreach ( )
{
    product.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var product in products)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> ProdItem = (List<Product>)LW.ItemsSource;
foreach (Product product in ProdItem)
{
    if (product.IsChecked == true) cupon_item++;
    product.IsChecked = false;
}
```